# Regex for range 1-1000

Tags: regex

I need help creating a simple regex for a whole number range of 1-1000, with no special characters.

The two I have both seem to break or allow characters or not the full range:

1. `^\d(\d)?(\d)?$`
2. `^[0-9]{1,3}$`

Comment: Is it just a practice? There is many libraries in almost any language to parse strings and convert to numeric data types.

Answer (score 50):

Try this:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)$
```

- **`[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`** matches any number between `1`–`999`
- **`1000`** matches `1000`

Comment: It gets rid of the special characters, but allows numbers >1000

Comment: it doesn't allow numbers > 1000.

Comment: I can't understand how this works. I would expect each set of brackets [] is 1 digit so that would be 1-99 or 1000. Can anyone explain?

Comment: For @jDub9 (And other future readers); `[1-9]` matches the first digit, from 1 to 9. The second chunk, `[0-9]{0,2}`, says the next character can be 0 to 9, and that there can be *zero to 2* (`{0,2}`) of these characters. This first section is functionally equivalent to `[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?`, and covers strings 1-999. Finally, the pipe `|` after that acts as an "OR" inside the capture group `()`, which means that a string can either match the first part, *or* literally match the string "1000" verbatim. You can see another [breakdown on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ifT1HS/).

Comment: Thanks @zcoop98 that's really helpful in demystifying Regular Expressions!

Answer (score 1):

Use `^(.*[^0-9]|)(1000|[1-9]\d{0,2})([^0-9].*|)$` which will match `1000` or a non-zero digit followed by up to two further digits. It will also allow other characters on either end of the number.

Comment: What about `1999`? ;-) And be careful with `\d` - it matches *any unicode digit* on unicode-enabled engines, not only `[0-9]`!

Comment: @Lucero 1999 is not in the range 1-1000. Unicode is *usually* disabled by default, but fair point.