# form validation of a text field

Tags: xml

Check format of a text field to be  XX-XXXX

first two digits represent any value between 01-99 are acceptable values
hyphen; 
last 4 digits represent any value between 0001 to 1,000

Comment: And you want to validate what? Is this a field in an html form input? Or maybe you're trying to validate an xml document using an xsd file? Ask your question properly and use the right tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try and be more specific in the future... I think I got the question right, but I'm not sure.

Give this a go! Don't forget to change the "fieldname" to your fieldname's actual name.

```
   <validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="fieldname">someThing</param>
        <message>Number Required.</message>
   </validator>

   <validator type="regex">
        <param name="fieldname">someThing</param>
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[\d{2}-\d{4}]></param>
        <message>Number must be entered as 99-9999.</message>
   </validator>
```

**This will only work for the formatting, not for the max-value of the second number.**

Have a look at [Regex for range 1-1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484168/regex-for-range-1-1000) 
and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206330/Learning-REGEX-regular-expression-in-the-most-easi