# REGEX range issue

Tags: regex

Slightly confused with regex range pattern to match any values in the range `0.000000` to `1.000000` (including the boundaries), for example:

```
0.000000 is valid
0.000001 is valid
0.999999 is valid
1.000000 is valid
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484168/regex-for-range-1-1000, and please Google before asking it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the required one:

```
^(0\.\d{6}|1\.0{6})$
```

`^` and `$` matches start and end

`0` matches a `0`

`\.` matches a `.`. `\` is to escape the special meaning of `.` in regex

`\d{6}` matches 6 digits

`1\.0{6}` matches `1.000000`

Comment: Also possible `[01]` in the beginning.

Comment: This will match `1.999999` that is not wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar. But your patter will also match 1.000009 (which is a false condition) as per the requirement. anything above 1.000000 is not acceptable. (sorry if my requirement was not very clear)

Comment: @DigitalDyn I've made required edit. Use `^(0\.\d{6}|1\.0{6})$`

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the proper tool to check number ranges, but your case is quite simple

```
\b(?:1\.0{6}|0\.\d{6})\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33uq5)

If the complete string does only consist of those numbers, you can change the word boundries `\b` to `^` start of the string and `$` end of the string

```
^(?:1\.0{6}|0\.\d{6})$
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression `0\.\d{6}|1\.0{6}`

> 0.    const 0.
>
> \d{6}  any 6 digits
>
> |      or
>
> 1.    const 1.
>
> 0{6}   const 000000

if you range does not contain other symbols but only this degit, you can use anchors, regex is `^0\.\d{6}|1\.0{6}$`

> ^      begin of string
>
> $      end of string