# Are these preg_match statements correct?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to build these regex statements for the preg matches but I am having a lot of trouble. Could someone please identify any that are wrong and provide the correct preg_match code.

Group name needs to be between 2 and 20 characters and contain uppercase and lowercase letters

Group size needs to be a number between 2 and 6

Postcode needs to be a valid uk postcode (government provided statement but unsure if correct implementation)

Budget needs to be a number between 1 and 10000

```
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z \']+$/', $group_name)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that group name contains only letters, apostrophes
                      and spaces and is between 2 and 20 characters long",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode); 
    } else if (!preg_match('/^([2-6])$/', $group_size)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that group size is between 2 and 6 people",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);
    } else if (!(preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode)
                 || preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode)
                 || preg_match("/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode))) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that the postcode is correct",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);
    } else if (!preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9][0-9]{0,2}|10000)$/', $budget)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure budget is between 1 and 10000 and contains only numbers",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);      if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z \']+$/', $group_name)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that group name contains only letters
                      and spaces and is between 2 and 20 characters long",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode); 
    } else if (!preg_match('/^([2-6])$/', $group_size)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that group size is between 2 and 6 people",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);
    } else if (!(preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode)
                 || preg_match("/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode)
                 || preg_match("/^GIR0[A-Z]{2}$/",$postcode))) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure that the postcode is correct",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);
    } else if (!preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9][0-9]{0,2}|10000)$/', $budget)) {
        unsuccessful("Please ensure budget is between 1 and 10000 and contains only numbers",
                     $group_name, $group_size, $postcode);
```

Thanks a lot

Kabeer

Comment: test regular express here : http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester

Comment: `if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z \']+$/', $group_name)) {` is not correct it won't be valid for apostrophes.

Comment: @A.P. I think these are better tools; [regexr](http://regexr.com) and [regex101](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: To test `$budget`, it's better to do: `if ($budget < 1 || $budget > 10000) { unsuccessful(...); }`

Comment: @M42 you mean to do a `< 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Group name needs to be between 2 and 20 characters and contain uppercase and lowercase letters**

- Create a range match between 2 and 20 of the preceding token.

```
/^[a-zA-Z \']{2,20}$/
```

**Group size needs to be a number between 2 and 6**

- This one was fine

```
/^([2-6])$/
```

**Postcode needs to be a valid uk postcode**

- According to [regexlib](http://www.regxlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=260&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), this will match UK postcodes

```
/^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$/
```

**Budget needs to be a number between 1 and 10000**

- Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484168/regex-for-range-1-1000)
- Tested [here](http://regexr.com/39q34)

```
/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]{0,2}|10000)$/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! with the first one I also want to accept apostrophes so /^[a-zA-Z \' \']{2,20}$/ is correct? Also the last one is 1 to 10000 so does /^([1-9][0-9][0-9]{0,2}|10000)$/ work for that?

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z \' \']{2,20}$/` is fine, however the one in the answer also accepts apostrophes. The regex won't match `1`. Updating answer now.

Comment: See updated answer for the 1-10000 range