# Multiple Min and Max value for textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a working code for entering valid minimum and maximum value in text box by using below code:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

But how about if I have multiple ranges allowed? For example: In my text box,  numbers from 1 to 5 and 10 to 15 is allowed, so numbers from 6-9 and 16 & up is not allowed. How to do this using javascript/jquery or angularjs?

Comment: you could use a regex

Comment: You need to create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. I tried it all but I got it by using if/else statement.

```
if (txt>=1 && txt<=5){
  return true
}
if (txt>=10 && txt<=15){
  return true
}
if (txt>=20 && txt<=25){
  return true
}else{
  alert("invalid")
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the html5 `pattern` attribute

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" pattern= "(1|2|3|4|5|10|11|12|13|14|15)" />
```

See [here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) website for further details.

Comment: Thanks but my given number is  just my example. I have big numbers its like: 100-1000 , 2000-3000 something like that.

Comment: You can keep adding to the pattern to limit it to the numbers you want. Check this post for details on how you would match numbers between `1-1000` You can tweak this regex to suit your needs.Without using JS i dont know any other way besides using `pattern` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484168/regex-for-range-1-1000

Comment: Thanks Paul I'll check it first.

Comment: This is *not* a good answer, because `pattern` does ot apply to `number` type inputs. From the docs: *This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email or password; otherwise it is ignored*.

Comment: @BramVanroy well spotted, I was not aware of that. Would `input type="text"` have any bad effect?

Comment: From what I have tested, text works okay. **However**, the input needs to be wrapped inside a form as well - at least in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. See this fiddle that I made: https://jsfiddle.net/04LknjrL/1 Also you might want to add a `title` attribute to provide the user with more feedback. The title will be included in the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `<select>`?

```html
<select name="quantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks But I have to input the number in the text box and my given number is just an example. What if I have ranges from tenths to thousands?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    <form name="form1" action="">
        <input type="text" name="quantity" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{2}|1000|2[0-9]{3}|3000" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecxqhjkp/1/

Answer (score 0):

To decouple the view from the business logic, you should use custom validators.

Provided you used an ngForm and ngModel for the input field like so:

```
<div ng-controller="InputController as inputCtrl">
  <ng-form name="testForm">
    <input type="text" name="testModel" ng-model="testModel"/>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

You can use the following controller:

```
app.controller('InputController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var validator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var isRange1To5 = modelValue >= 1 && modelValue <= 5;
        var isRange10To15 = modelValue >= 10 && modelValue <= 15;

        return isRange1To5 || isRange10To15;
    };

    $scope.testForm.testModel.$validators['rangeValidator'] = validator;
}])
```

The min/max directives (and others) just work like this. They add a validator to the model - which is executed each time the input changes.

For more information, see Angular's docs on the issue:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation