# Regex to match an amount range

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to match an amount in a range of 10 to 10000 (inclusive)
So far I came up with something like this:

```
^(?:[1-9]\\d{0,3}?)$
```

But there are two problems with it:

- It matches anything up to 10 for example 5
- It excludes 10000

I know using regular expression to match a range is not the greatest idea, but it has to be done this way.

Comment: See a [similar question, `1` to `1000`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484168/regex-for-range-1-1000)

Comment: try with `^(?:[1-9]\\d{1,4}?)$`

Comment: Check [`^([1-9][0-9]{1,3}|10000)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pT7wK6/1)

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew looks like it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^([1-9][0-9]{1,3}|10000)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT7wK6/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `([1-9][0-9]{1,3}|10000)` - an alternation with 2 options:

  - `[1-9][0-9]{1,3}` - a digit from 1 to 9, followed with 1 to 3 any digits (the `{1,3}` is important to exclude matching `5` and all numbers up to `10`), and it matches integer numbers from `10` till `9999` with no leading zeros.
  - `|` - or
  - `10000` - a 10000 number
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

You can say something like:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{1,3}|10000)$
```

See it in a test: https://regex101.com/r/wK4bC6/6

This mathces either `10000` or `[1-9][0-9]{0,3}`, this second one being any number from 10 to 9999.